# How to change icon on the SlidingDrawer handle when clicked

Tags: android, slider

Im trying to change the icon on the handle when i try to open the slidingdrawer.
When I extract the handle from the view and sets the onclicklistener or ontouchlistener it seems to never get trigget.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    SlidingDrawer drawer = (SlidingDrawer)findViewById(R.id.drawer_landscape);

    ImageView handle = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.handle_l);
    handle.setFocusable(true);

    handle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("test","onClick");
        }

    });


}
```

And my XML

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:id="@+id/base_frame_layout"
     android:layout_gravity="bottom"
     >        
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <TextView  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/hello"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

        <SlidingDrawer
             android:id="@+id/drawer_landscape"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:handle="@+id/handle_l"
             android:content="@+id/content"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:visibility="visible"
        >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/handle_l"
                android:layout_height="50px"
                android:layout_width="64px"
                android:padding="0px"
                android:src="@drawable/icon"
            />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/content" 
                android:text="content" 
                android:layout_height="50px"
                android:layout_width="64px"
            />                  

         </SlidingDrawer>       

</FrameLayout>
```

I was hoping this code should log "onClick" message, but it doesn't.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it, it was pritty easy... I just need to setOnDrawerScrollListener on my drawer.

than implement the 2 methods onScrollEnded and onScrollStarted.

```
    mSlidingDrawer.setOnDrawerScrollListener(new OnDrawerScrollListener(){

        @Override
        public void onScrollEnded() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("ddd","onScrollEnded slider");
            slider_animation.reverseTransition(HANDLE_ANIMATION_SPEED);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStarted() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("ddd","onScrollStarted slider");
            slider_animation.startTransition(HANDLE_ANIMATION_SPEED);
        }

});
```

I rather use an animation on the handle instead of changing the Image bacause of the flickering.

Comment: What does your animation xml file look like?

Answer (score -1):

I found it for along time , but now it is completed about it .
It is the best way for Change Image Handle when you click to view SlidingDrawer.

It have 2 Method that we use in code below.

```
final SlidingDrawer drawer = (SlidingDrawer)findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawer);

    drawer.setOnDrawerOpenListener(new SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerOpenListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened() {
            arr.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrowdown);
        }
    });
    drawer.setOnDrawerCloseListener(new SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed() {
            arr.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrowup);
        }
    });
```